# Anchor tag with download prop skips contents after #039; character

Tags: html, download, href, anchor

I'm using an anchor tag to export my data to a csv file:

```html
  <a href="data:text;charset=utf-8,1,2,3,4,5" download="myfile.csv">Download</a>
```

But sometimes there is a `'` character in the data that is escaped to `#039`. If so, the file after this character is not exporting!
**Example:**

```html
<a href="data:text;charset=utf-8,Start #039; This will be skipped" download="myfile.csv">Download</a>
```

You can see this bug here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rostamiani/xswar3fj/

- How can I avoid this problem without changing the data source?
- Why this happens and how to avoid?
- Is there any other characters like this?

## **UPDATE:**

The problem is not `#039` character, it's exactly `#`.

See the new example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rostamiani/xswar3fj/2/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while downloading a file and solved this by using the `encodeURIComponent()` function.

My download code looks like this:

```js
const downloadDocument() => {
  let a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  a.download = 'export.html';
  a.href = `data:text/html, ${encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector("iframe[id]").contentDocument.querySelector("html").innerHTML)}`;
  a.click();
};
```

The resultant href string looks something like this `<a href="data:text/html,%3Chead%3E%3Cmeta%20http-equiv%3D%22Content-Type%22%20content%3D%22text%" download="export.html">Download</a>`

The `encodeURIComponent` function will escape the # symbol using the UTF-8 encoding of the character. Once the downloadDocument function is called, the document is downloaded and the contents are preserved.